# How to get one value from several identical ones?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, knex.js

As an example I have such records in my DB:

```
product_id
------------------------------------
887349c7-699e-4792-adde-3a44acd2d768
887349c7-699e-4792-adde-3a44acd2d768
887349c7-699e-4792-adde-3a44acd2d768
ecdcf200-6bc0-4b67-b47a-5946a1ab1dcf
ecdcf200-6bc0-4b67-b47a-5946a1ab1dcf
01a5419d-aaf8-4524-99ce-9bf5c1836823
01a5419d-aaf8-4524-99ce-9bf5c1836823
```

How can I get (using `MySQL` or `Knex.js` syntax) every `product_id`, but only 1, because I have copies (it's okay, this is how it has to be):

```
product_id
------------------------------------
887349c7-699e-4792-adde-3a44acd2d768
ecdcf200-6bc0-4b67-b47a-5946a1ab1dcf
01a5419d-aaf8-4524-99ce-9bf5c1836823
```

Comment: Simply use the `DISTINCT` key word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Inside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: One more question, what if I have also `NULL` in `product_id`, but need ALL records (with `NULL` too). I checked it with `count()` function, and it doesn't seem to count records with `NULL`

Comment: Use two queries and combine them with `UNION`. One should return all the non-null values with `DISTINCT`, the other should return all the null values.

Comment: Yes. Because COUNT() can not count null values. Do you wanna count how many NULL do you have?

Comment: Actually, I always have record which has `NULL`, so, if I have 5 records, 1 of them always will be `NULL`

Comment: You can count Null with this query:  select count(coalesce(YOURCOLUMN, 'bingo')) NVALUES from YOURTABLE where coalesce(YOURCOLUMN, 'bingo') = 'bingo' group by YOURCOLUMN

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to group by the column

```
SELECT column
FROM table
GROUP BY column
```

If you're getting these duplicates because of a join to a table with multiple rows for this one row, it would be better to use any possibly ways of reducing the amount of data to be joined rather than generating lots of duplicates and then having to dedicate resources to squishing them afterwards

For example if you've got person joined to address, and address keeps a history of everywhere that person has lived, the current address being given by a leave_date that is null (a person has only one active address), it would be better to do:

```
SELECT person.* 
FROM person JOIN address ON ...
WHERE address.leave_date IS NULL
```

Than do

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.*
FROM person JOIN address ON ...
```

In short, your response to "OMG, I'm getting duplicates" shouldn't always be "just ram a distinct in there to get rid of them", it should be "why did they appear and is there a way to eg cut down a 1:M join to 1:1 so they don't appear in the first place?"